# start /realtime with a .bat file but the process is still not realtime

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, batch-file, priority

I have created a .BAT file:

```
start /realtime "c:\software\mysoftware.exe"
```

but when launching it on Windows 10, it's not displayed as"Realtime" in the `Task Manager`. What can be the potential problems preventing it to start as realtime?

Note: the goal is to make it start realtime at the startup of Windows (i.e. I was thinking about creating a shortcut to the .BAT in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`)

Comment: Have you tried running the batch file as administrator?

Comment: I think I had tried, but still I will retry to be sure @iTechieGamer. Right click, Run as administrator, is that still correct with Win10?

Comment: @iTechieGamer If it works with this, how to make Run as administrator at Windows startup? Will a shortcut in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` offer an option to run as admin with Win10? (My habits are Win7, so not 100% sure how it is on Win10)

Comment: We can use task scheduler to run the batch file as administrator on startup.

Comment: Is this the only way @iTechieGamer? No `Start Menu > Startup`  shortcut would work as admin?

Comment: I believe that is the only way.

Comment: @iTechieGamer Would you have a link showing how to create such a task as admin?

Comment: Link is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5427673
Does it start the program with realtime priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @iTechieGamer, a task scheduler task solves the problem:

```
schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn MySoftware /rl highest /tr  "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\launchit.bat"
```

(this needs to be done with cmd.exe launched as admin!)

with this `launchit.bat`:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\"
start /realtime mysoftware.exe
```